# SUMming SUMs connected through UNION in MySQL and display using ECHO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sum, echo, union

For every surgical center I have built MySQL SUM queries which summarize the number of surgical procedures performed. In PHP I display the results in a table with two columns.

Now, I want to calculate the SUM over the SUMs of all centers and display them likewise.

The problem is that the same echo command does show the kind of surgcial procedures below each other, but only the very first of the SUM over SUMs result (cf. 3.)

The PHP function code and SQL query code look like this:

```
function getGlobalAlleOPVerfahrenStratification() {
  global $oDatabase;
  $qQuery = ' 
  SELECT SUM(X1.Surgery1) AS "Surgery1" FROM (
    SELECT SUM(op.OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Surgery1"
    FROM operation op
    UNION
    SELECT SUM(op.OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Surgery1"
    FROM operation op
    UNION
    SELECT SUM(op.OPVerfahren = "20") AS "Surgery1"
    FROM operation op
  ) X1
  UNION
  SELECT SUM(X2.Surgery2) AS "Surgery2" FROM (
    SELECT SUM(op.OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Surgery2"
    FROM operation op
    UNION
    SELECT SUM(op.OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Surgery2"
    FROM operation op
    UNION
    SELECT SUM(op.OPVerfahren = "20") AS "Surgery2"
    FROM operation op
  ) X2; ';

  $rQuery = mysql_query($qQuery, $oDatabase);
  $result = array("count" => mysql_num_rows($rQuery), "result" => $rQuery);
  return $result;
}


function writeGlobalOP1OPVerfahrenStratification($rQuery) {
  if (!$rQuery) {
    $message = '<br>';
    $message .= '<b>Ungültige Abfrage:</b> ' . mysql_error() . '<br>';
    $message .= '<b>Gesamte Abfrage:</b> ' . $qQuery . '<br>';
    echo $message;
  }

  if (mysql_num_rows($rQuery) == 0) {
    $message = '<br>';
    $message .= '<p class="error">Zu diesem Zeitraum liegen noch keine Daten vor.</p> ' . mysql_error() . '<br>';
    echo $message;
  }

  //echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<th style="font-size: 30px; border-left: 6px solid blue;">';
  echo "Alle Zentren";
  echo '</th>';
  echo '<th class="data_table_r" style="font-size: 30px;">';
  echo "Summen";
  echo '</th>';
  echo '</tr>';

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rQuery)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="font-size: 30px; border-left: 6px solid blue;">';
    echo "Operation 1";
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td class="data_table_r" style="font-size: 30px;">';
    echo $row['Surgery1'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td style="font-size: 30px; border-left: 6px solid blue;">';
    echo "Operation 2";
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td class="data_table_r" style="font-size: 30px;">';
    echo $row['Surgery2'];
    echo '</table>';
    }
}
```

Instead of all the

```
echo ...
```

commands after the while statement, by simply writing

```
echo $row['Surgery1'];
echo '<br />';
```

PHP displays the Surgeries one after another separated by a carriage return

However, what I expect is a table with two columns in the left of which the Operation name is given and in the right of which the number of surgeries is listed.

Sorry, but I am too stupid to realize this.

Has anyone, please, a solution for me?

Comment: Both halves of your top-level `UNION` are the same, is that intended? and neither include an operation name, only a count of types of `OPVerfahren `)

Comment: i would write     SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN op.OPVerfahren = "0" THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS "Surgery1"
    FROM operation op for all those sibqueries

Comment: @Nick: Thank you, there were three little mistakes when transcirbing, I eliminated them. The SQL query, inserted natively into an SQL editor, shows the results (correctly), so I am getting the values for "Surgery1" and "Surgery2". I have no idea, though, how to get them displayed line by line with the preceding description in the while statement.

Comment: @nbk: Thank you for the advice, I have done this already, but it comes to the same result: The data results are available, but I am wondering if they are put into the very first array only.

Comment: @mtjmohr column names are set by the first `SELECT` in a `UNION`, so all your `Surgery2` values will be in `$row['Surgery1']` and there will never be a `$row['Surgery2']` value.

Comment: @mtjmohr the internals of the `UNION` query are still identical so they will both give the same results.

Comment: @Nick: Ah, this is a first evidence. So do you think I should not make this UNION of X1 and X2 but a specific query for each?

Comment: It would probably be easier. The alternative might be a JOIN between X1 & X2 but as they have no logical column to JOIN on that might run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Union only combines rows that aren't identical. So for your purposes union isn't the right choice in all cases.

So with this table

```
CREATE TABLE operation
(`id` int, `OPVerfahren` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO operation
(`id`, `OPVerfahren`)
VALUES
(1, '0'),
(2, '1'),
(4, '0'),
(5, '20'),
(6, '0'),
(7, '1'),
(8, '20'),
(9, '0'),
(10, '0')
;
```

And this select statement

```
    SELECT "Surgery1",SUM(IF (op.OPVerfahren = "0",1,
               if( op.OPVerfahren = "1",1,
                if (op.OPVerfahren = "20", 1,0)
                 )
              )
          ) "Surgery1"
  FROM operation op
  union
  SELECT "Surgery2", SUM(IF (op.OPVerfahren = "0",1,
               if( op.OPVerfahren = "1",1,
                if (op.OPVerfahren = "20", 1,0)
                 )
              )
          ) "Surgery2"
FROM operation op
```

You get  following result

```
Surgery1    Surgery1
Surgery1    9
Surgery2    9
```

Which is the correct result for this example.
Of course you have it to adept to your actual structre and data

I personally would have done following

```
    SELECT SUM(IF (op.OPVerfahren = "0",1,
               if( op.OPVerfahren = "1",1,
                if (op.OPVerfahren = "20", 1,0)
                 )
              )
          ) "Surgery1",
          SUM(IF (op.OPVerfahren = "0",1,
               if( op.OPVerfahren = "1",1,
                if (op.OPVerfahren = "20", 1,0)
                 )
              )
          ) "Surgery2"
FROM operation op
```

Which would got you

```
Surgery1    Surgery2
9           9
```

But your original it seems taht you wanted two rows, so....